# Unable to connect to docker container inside windows server

Tags: docker

As title.  I am developing a system with many docker images with ASP.Net MVC core projects.  I am publishing these docker images into a docker engine installed on Windows Server OS, and I found that I can't open pages in the docker container on the server from client side.  Here are the situations I've met when I find that I can't call these APIs from these docker images:

- Because of windows based, no networks with bridge drivers inside docker networks.
- Open pages inside these docker images in the server is OK.
- Firewall rules are set to make needed ports can be accessed.

  Could someone guide me to fix it?

The result of running command`docker info`:

```
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  app: Docker App (Docker Inc., v0.9.1-beta3)
  cluster: Manage Mirantis Container Cloud clusters (Mirantis Inc., v1.9.0)
  registry: Manage Docker registries (Docker Inc., 0.1.0)

Server:
 Containers: 2
  Running: 1
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 1
 Images: 3
 Server Version: 20.10.9
 Storage Driver: windowsfilter
  Windows:
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: ics internal l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay private transparent
  Log: awslogs etwlogs fluentd gcplogs gelf json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Default Isolation: process
 Kernel Version: 10.0 17763 (17763.1.amd64fre.rs5_release.180914-1434)
 Operating System: Windows Server 2019 Standard Version 1809 (OS Build 17763.4010)
 OSType: windows
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 8GiB
 Name: ITTSCRMDB
 ID: AQYX:7V62:VD2W:LNLC:WOLS:VCIH:6K6R:DC3R:S6XW:O3EF:QHRL:PAVA
 Docker Root Dir: C:\ProgramData\docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

And the result of running command `docker network ls` :

```
NETWORK ID     NAME      DRIVER    SCOPE
a96e452c5a6c   nat       nat       local
ca3ffe37f040   nat2      nat       local
f0bf64220013   none      null      local
```

My dockerfile (automatic generated from Visual Studio):

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["A/A.csproj", "A/"]
COPY ["B/B.csproj", "B/"]
COPY ["C/C.csproj", "C/"]
RUN dotnet restore "C/C.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/C"
RUN dotnet build "C.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "C.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "C.dll"]
```

Comment: I have same issue before, and I still not found a solution. for somehow my container port mapping is not correctly. You can check if is same issue by execute `netstat -ano` in powershell, see if your host does listening 0.0.0.0 or not.

Comment: @Charlie The target of the command is....the server or the docker container?  I know that I could use ```docker exec -it <<container name>>``` to execute the command.

Comment: On server, the purpose checking `netstat -ano` is make sure that your request from client will passed to container. And the premise of this behavior is that you have correctly set up port mapping.

Comment: Since you didn't provide your `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml`, I don't even have a way to confirm that your container configuration is correct.

Comment: Dockerfile added, and I didn't have ```docker-compose.yml```.